# Ошибка в запросе

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс

Написала код в классе:

```html
$strSql = "UPDATE ".$this->suppliers." SET `date_update_bitrix`=NOW(),`flag_1c_bitrix`=0 where id='".$resAr['id']."'";
echo $strSql;
$res = $this->DB->Query($strSql);
echo $strSql;
```

Пишет первое `echo $strSql;` и возникает ошибка следующего содержания:

```html
UPDATE it_suppliers SET `date_update_bitrix`=NOW(),`flag_1c_bitrix`=0 where id='37'
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="35%" bgcolor="#9C9A9C">
 <tr>
  <td><table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">
     <FONT face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="-1">
     <font color="#FF0000"><b>DB query error.</b></font><br>
     Please try later.
     </font><br>
         </td>
   </tr>
  </table></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>
```

Если запрос ('UPDATE it_suppliers SET `date_update_bitrix`=NOW(),`flag_1c_bitrix`=0 where id='37'
    ') вставить в хейди, то без проблем выполняется. Подключение  к базе идет. Сначала выполняется без проблем `select` с этой же таблицы,но `update` с проблемами.
**UPD**
Запрос к базе делается след. образом в компоненте, где вызывается объект класса:

```html
global $DB;
 $DBHost = $DB->DBHost;
 $DBName = "1c";
 $DBLogin = $DB->DBLogin;
 $DBPassword = $DB->DBPassword;
 
 $DB_1c = new CDatabase;
 if(!$DB_1c->Connect($DBHost, $DBName, $DBLogin, $DBPassword)) {
  if(file_exists($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].BX_ROOT."/php_interface/dbconn_error.php")) {
   include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].BX_ROOT."/php_interface/dbconn_error.php");
  } else {
   include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].BX_ROOT."/modules/main/include/dbconn_error.php");
  }
  die();
 }
 
        $DB_1c->Query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$obCatalog = new CIBlock;
$obCatalog->InitEx($NS, array(
 "IBLOCK_ID" => 1,
    "OFFERS_IBLOCK_ID" => 4,
 "DB" => $DB_1c,
 "DATE_LAST_IMPORT" => $dateLastImport
));
    $obCatalog->UpdateFrom_it_suppliers();// вот там вызов select без проблем , а update c "заглушкой"
```

Comment: Это просто заглушка. Установите в `db_conn.php` дебаг константы в тру и смотрите в чем ошибка конкретно.

Comment: $DBDebug = true; и см. ошибку

Comment: стоит, когда выполняется отлично, когда не выполняется... А надо, чтобы выполнялось всегда. Никакой текст ошибки не выдает, кроме указанной. Это не подключение к базе битрикса, это подключение к другой базе. Опишу в задаче.

Comment: Абсолютно неясный комментарий, что стоит, что выполняется. В новом коде также неясно как происходит запрос.

Comment: @u_mulder,@jekaby , может ли эта "заглушка" происходить из-за нехватки памяти на компе. У меня слабый комп- с 2гб оперативки. Просто тестирую на компе- опенсервере.

Comment: С нехваткой памяти на компе скрипт упадет с фатал еррором и никакой битрикс этого не перехватит. Нарисуйте отдельно php-страницу с этим запросом и попытайтесь выполнить.

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = $DB->Query($strSql);
```